# Story Identification - children's novel about a boy running away to play Dungeons and Dragons

Tags: story-identification, dragons

When I was a kid I remember reading a short novel about a boy secretly running away and playing Dungeons and Dragons (or a similar game) with some rougher kids. The whole thing was told as though he was doing something underhand or wrong, like getting in with the wrong crowd or taking drugs! I remember there was a focus on him getting lost in the game and having to come back with a miniature to play with as a sort of initiation.
I can't remember what it was called and I want to find it again. I think it was called something like 'A Road to Nowhere' but searches for that have got me nothing. Also I think there was a motorbike on the cover.
Any ideas?!

Comment: Maybe you can find it through Wikipedia? [D&D in pop culture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons_in_popular_culture#Books)

Comment: Makes me think of one of the [Chick Tracts](http://www.chick.com/reading/tracts/0046/0046_01.ASP) -- ugh.

Comment: Hey, don't go breaking on Chick Tracts, they were an important part of the kitsch of my childhood. I'm still looking for the one I read circa 1980 where they were all hysterically over the top predicting that someday soon in American, gay people would be getting married! ...hmmm probably a bad example.

Comment: @TechZen I like the one where the [guy grows up to be on the FBI 10 most wanted because his parents let him believe Santa is real](http://www.chick.com/reading/tracts/1033/1033_01.asp).

Comment: @DampeS8N - I love the way its just glossed over that the kid *started* with having no techniques to deal with rather mild taunts and name-calling that don't leave a classmate dead, and no visible regret even before he learned about the lies.  Nope, totally Santa's fault.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there are no actual fantasy or sci-fi aspects to the question.

Answer (score 4):

It may prove very difficult to find this specific novel, unless someone else read it too.

You may have read [Hobgoblin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobgoblin_%28book%29) or possibly the novel [Mazes and Monsters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazes_and_Monsters_%28novel%29) which was turned into a movie starring Tom Hanks by the same name. There were also a few other 'me too' novels that will be harder to find as, again, they all have the same plot.

Neither Hobgoblin or Mazes and Monsters have a cover with a motorbike on it or a gang of ruffians, however, so I would guess it was one of the aforementioned knockoffs. Those are really hard to draw a bead on. Hopefully someone else has read that specific book.

All of these are very similar stories that parallel the life of [James Egbert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Dallas_Egbert_III) who was a young man whose disappearance was blamed on D&D for a variety of silly reasons. It sparked a national controversy which both promoted and almost destroyed D&D.

Comment: I was a big D&D geek back then and that all ticked us off royally. "Look it's just a past time that engages our brains, what you want us to spend 12 hours every weekend watching sports on TV?"

Comment: ''Hobgoblin'' is a weird case in that his obsession with the D&D analogue is what saves all of the kids in the end. The only way it's ever shown as negative is that it makes it a little harder to socialize with a certain crowd, who are also shown to be violent bullies.